# Why I can't insert data from form with text 'insert' in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I try to save / update data with text "...That means you may **insert** keywords into the title of a page where ever ....." It shows 500 internal server error, and when I save without "**insert**" word in above text it easily saves in database. The same thing happens when I use the reserved words like **update**, **delete** in the field to add/update in the database. The error is due to the reserved word of mysql, isn't there any ways to get rid of it?

I am using CodeIgniter and code to update above text is :

```
function update_template($id,$newtext,$newcomptext)

    {       
            $data=array(
            'option_value'=>$newtext,
            'competitive_value'=>$newcomptext
            );
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $this->db->update('report_texts', $data); 

            return 'Successfully Updated';


    }
```

I would be much thankful for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using the lastQuery() function to find out what it's actually inserting?

Comment: Set db_debug to true in database.php so that CI will out put what it was executing when the error happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that the word "INSERT" in the text you're writing to the database is causing an SQL error (INSERT is generally a reserved word in SQL implementations).

In any case, the CI framework says, "Oh, we have a problem. I should return a 500 error message" as a result of the error it gets back from the database.

**EDIT**

The $this->db->escape() function doesn't help this because $this->db->query() already escapes your values.

Comment: Actually AR is supposed to automatically escape all inputs, so you should'nt need calling $this->db->escape(). Strange.